# uBlock Origin: Allow YouTube Ads

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, adblock

I tried allowing YouTube Ads with `no-cosmetic-filtering: youtube.com true` but it seems like that it still blocks Ads (At least I don't see any Ads on YouTube anymore)
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Edit: I don't want to disable the extension completely, I just want to allow Ads, but block any tracking. I have to same problem for 9gag.com, I would like to allow Ads with `no-cosmetic-filtering: 9gag.com true` but Ads are still blocked (There are only grey fields)

Comment: Disable the add-on from browser settings menu.

Comment: I would like to make a rule, without completley whitelisting YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow some YouTube channels in uBlock Origin and know
the exact channel name (case sensitive), do :

- Open Add-ons manager
- Find uBlock Origin and click Preferences
- Select "show dashboard"
- Click Whitelist
- Type in the following

  ```
  youtube.com/*user=<<channel name>>
  ```

If you wish to white-list all the channels, you may install
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
or
[Violentmonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/violent-monkey/jinjaccalgkegednnccohejagnlnfdag),
then visit the userscript
[YouTube - whitelist channels in uBlock Origin](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/22308-youtube-whitelist-channels-in-ublock-origin)
and click on "Install this script".
Clicking on the nearby question-mark will show additional help.

Comment: Are you sure there is no "inbuild" option to whitelist ads on YouTube? I don't want to use additional scripts, also I dont want to whitelist just one YouTube channel.

Comment: I can't be sure, I only don't know of another method.

Comment: If you want to allow all YouTube ads I think that would be enough changing the last step and just using `youtube.com/*` (as I understand you weren't using the whitelist but another option).